# correct technical term for "timeline algebra"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $S$ is a set and $G$ is a group of functions from $S$ to $S$ under composition (not necessarily *all* functions $S\to S$, but closed under composition), and additionally for all $s_1, s_2$ in $S$ there exists a unique $g$ in $G$ such that $g(s_1) = s_2$ does this have a technical name?

As a concrete example, $S$ could be the set of all date times and $G$ could be the set of all functions that add / subtract a fixed duration from those date times

Answer (score 0):

The name is not timeline algebra :)

In general groups which come from functions like that are called [permutation groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group). An important, although easy, result in group theory is that all groups can be represented as permutation groups.

The restriction you give are restrictions on the natural [group action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) on $S$. In particularly I would describe your type of action as a free and transitive action. I have also heard simply transitive or sharply transitive to describe this.

A free action describes the uniqueness, and transitive is the for any two points $x,y$ there is a $g$ such that $g(x)=y$ part. Every group has a free and transitive action on a set by acting on itself by left multiplication. It should be clear that not all groups behave like your timeline algebra example, groups can be way more complicated!